# Fourier transform in Mathematica

Tags: fourier-analysis, mathematical-software, st.statistics

R and Mathematica software differ when computing `fft(c(1,1))` and `Fourier[{1,1}]`,

2+0i 0+0i

and

{1.41421+ 0i, 0} respectively. How can this be????

Comment: off topic, see the FAQ

Comment: Obviously, they're using different definitions.  The notation and conventions associated with the Fourier transform differ between different authors, although it's usually easy to figure out the differences and adjust your results accordingly.  A look at the documentation for the R and Mathematica functions should help you figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalizing factor.

It looks like R defines the Discrete Fourier Transform matrix as $F = [1$  $1; 1$ $-1]$ while Mathematica defines it as $F = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}[1$  $1; 1$ $-1]$.

If you do inverse fft - R would define it to be $F^{-1} = \frac{1}{2}[1$  $1; 1$ $-1]$ while Mathematica would define it as $F^{-1} = F^{H} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}[1$  $1; 1$ $-1]$ where $H$ is Hermitian transpose.